# Dear Olin and his small gang

Tags: discussion

Not that you will "make it past the first line" I'm sure, however I am leaving this site and deleting the app I have viewed daily- because of you. Not only you, but the small ring that emulates you because they wish to align themselves with powerful egos.

I have learned a great deal as a hobbyist from these posts (including your very organized succinct answers), however there is a growing trend on this site that is bordering on covert and even sometimes overt racism, prejudice and bullying under the guise of 'respect for our volunteers'. For the record, this is not intended as slander, only the opinion of myself and possibly those that feel the same. Let's call a spade a pure, simple spade and cut the shit. You are not here out of a bleeding heart for these peoples circuit problems. You are here because of a love of your field and to drum up business, reputation and status as an expert. You do help educate people. You also belittle, insult and patronize two classes of people. 1. Beginners who are not as meticulous as yourself and 2. People who are using English as a second Language. I have read on multiple posts from multiple people "We speak English here.. Voting to close". The business language of the world is English, so those from smaller countries are forced to do their best to communicate. Are some of the posts sloppy, disorganized and lacking in vital info? Of course. Then don't answer you baby, and move on. You claim it's to shame and teach them what is expected. I have seen others accomplish this without ever sinking to your 'Oh I am so abused here' complaining. The fact that you feel the need to type it over and over and over reveals to those with psychological wisdom WHY you do it (I'll leave it a mystery for you to work out). It's disgusting and plain boring. Congratulations on spreading hate and elitism masked as discipline. There are other gurus with firm expectations, but also display patience, compassion and are free from high school drama. Take care. Thank you to those who helped a passing hobbyist out. Cheers.

Comment: Olin is like our angry old grandpa LOL! Don't mind him. He just wants our website to have intelligent questions that require people to know what they've done wrong. He won't answer questions that people hardly put in effort to ask. There's a difference between not knowing the answer and not know what you've done wrong. Olin is a very well known in the EE community... I'm not just talking about on StackExchange.

Answer (score 13):

I reckon that this site strives to a quality level sometimes higher than others in the SE network, but I agree with the OP that there is more and more tolerance towards plain rudeness, and much less towards novices.

Voting and reviewing can go a long way to help keeping the site tidy and high quality, but I believe we should make a better effort into easing people on the site, otherwise we'll miss many valid contributors. And not only novices, but I've seen also reputable users take distance from the site because of this trend.

Comment: Honestly, it strives, but it's far from reaching the _average_ quality level of other technical SE sites.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano could that perhaps be because 'Electrical Engineering' tends to end up being the default catch-all for anyone with a 'question' about 2 bits of wire who thinks stuff works like it does in the movies?

Comment: @brhans well you could say the same about any topic, there are always those who think something is easier than it really is. But the community rules are to be nice to others, even if the questions they ask seem silly to us.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Can you please back-up your claim with some data or some examples? From what indicators do you deduce that we are "... far from reaching the average quality level of other technical SE sites". I can accept criticism about EE.SE being somewhat unwelcoming compared to other SE sites (something which I regret and try to counter), but if you express such a drastic judgement about this site's *quality*, then you should at least provide some meaningful argument. Otherwise you appear just as insulting to our contributors as some of our members are to newbies.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati This site is careless on different aspects, from attribution of image and text sources (how many images here without attribution!) to the usage of LaTeX, and it's weak on several theoretical aspects of electronics. For the last point, if I had time and motivation I could certainly find examples, and a few can be found in my comments, but what's for? Should we discuss case by case? I have no interest in such a discussion (e.g. I had enough of [this discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53134/discussion-on-answer-by-andy-aka-why-do-transformers-use-so-many-turns)).

Comment: Note also that this not only my idea, but it's shared by other professionals with whom I discussed the topic.

Answer (score 8):

#### The rants

I'll quickly comment on the rants first, but feel free to skip down to the *important* point below.

> there is a growing trend on this site that is bordering on covert and even sometimes overt racism, prejudice and bullying

Hardly a "growing trend", unless you compare with 2009.

> Beginners who are not as meticulous as yourself

*Read:* Posts questions before trying to find an answer themselves.

> those from smaller countries are forced to do their best to communicate

Sometimes the best is not good enough. Usually it is, but no medals are given for just showing up to the race.

> free from high school drama

The only one who's adding drama is you. *"I am leaving this site and deleting the app"*.

#### The actual issue

> Then don't answer you baby, and move on.

This is not how Stack Exchange is set up to work. On the surface it may look as a place where anyone can get help with their personal problems. That's really only a "side effect".

The goal of the Stack Exchange network is to build up a repository of **high quality answers** to **high quality questions**.

The problem with the old forum model is that all the good questions and answers *drown* in the noise that comes when everyone keeps asking the same thing over and over, without knowing how to even ask a question! It doesn't help when everyone who knows how to use a keyboard tries to answer.

For this to work, we can't "move on". We have to remove the crap. The crap is removed by voting, and Olin's vote is worth exactly as much as my vote, and everyone else's.

Comment: I got to know about Olin from one of my only question which got negative vote. I appreciate the end goal towards making EE.SE an end high quality answer place but found a downside from following followers. Suppose one question got negative review and instantly other users start downvoting and all hard earned reputation goes in vein. I would really appreciate if this kind of herd following could be stopped.

Comment: @PrasanDutt What makes you think it's a "herd following"? If one user thinks that a question is bad, chances are that other users will think it is bad. Votes are secret. If many users downvotes, it's a bad question and should be closed until it is improved. If you don't stick around to improve it, well, no one can force you to do that. Note that _many_ users manages to write coherent questions.

Comment: I mean before even editing, got many downvotes. If a question is bad, there should be a time frame to improve it. If I don't understand something I may ask questions in such a way that others might think a dumb question but it would be a genuine problem for me.

Comment: @PrasanDutt I heartily disagree. Downvote a question when it's badly written. Not later. The duty to write a good question is upon the asker, not the reader. I regularly retract my downvotes when an edit to a question has moved the question from "underresearched, bad" to "appropriately showing own effort, sufficiently (but not great) in description of the problem". Very seldom, an edit is good enough to convert my downvote to an upvote.

Comment: @PrasanDutt, Delete your question and you get all your reputation points back.

Comment: @ThePhoton very good point, I tried it but it prompts 'you cannot delete this question, someone put time and effort in answering this question'. I know the answer will help someone in future, what to do in this case?

Comment: Then the only thing is ask some better (more researched, more carefully stated) questions. One up-vote cancels 2.5 down-votes.

Comment: @Photon  How about you delete your patronising comment  with poorly researched incorrect advice suggesting a deletion.  Also I have not removed my bloopers on SE even though it might gain me some monopoly money.  I am usually soundly chastened or unrepentant and in the right even if they might have negative votes so there is more value to leaving them for the future readers who may stumble upon them.

Answer (score 4):

This site is not exactly friendly towards hobbyists because that group wants to post *project posts*, which is fine but a lot of professionals do not want to deal with these types of questions.

Some of the project questions here are show and tell questions, that is not the purpose of this site. This is a site to ask questions and get answers, the more specific you make the questions the better answer you will get. Questions should not require clarification, if people have to make comments and improve your question, then there is a problem. So write clearly and think the questions out before posting (like actually visit the help center for guidelines, make sure its a post worthy topic). It can take some time and effort to communicate clearly and its a learning process.

People could be a little more lenient and give a more leeway to people who are newer. On the other hand, people that are new need to make an effort to understand how the community works. There are also channels you can use (ask a moderator, meta or flagging) if people are really being rude, SE's policy is "Be nice" make sure the comments are worth a moderators time to look at.

Realize also that you are getting free access to experts, and their time is worth money they don't want to waste time clarifying others questions. I would recommend coming into EE.SE with a thick skin and a will to learn about the community.

Comment: The critical members of this community keep complaining about the quality of questions and how they will train and educate people to ask properly.  The least effort is with a vote.  Leaving a negative non-constructive comment takes work and is an ego thing and not an educational thing or the core purpose of EE.SE or other bits of SE.  There is the constant efar that too much bad stuff is in the face of the experts that they will get upset, by your definition they should have a thick skin but choose not to use it.  Most people find answers on SE via Google et.al. who cares how they got there.

Comment: Additionally, as for the experts' time, a mouse click and the frustration is gone far faster than a snide comment.  Having subscribed here a while back and read stuff somewhat earlier I am reminded weekly why SE is not something I do every day.  The critical/condescending/superior attitude of the moderators makes me feel violated, occasionally on EE.SE but almost every visit on some other stacks  I still try to find the occasional question to answer in spite of it.  The SF&F almost always cheers me up.  Supporting this status quo makes you part of the problem, #metoo

Comment: I actually don't support the status quo, I think my voting record and comments in the last 6 months supports that if you care to check it out. I do put in a lot of time on this site cleaning up other peoples messes. I do support good questions and I try to 'be nice' I still get annoyed when people with 100 rep or less could care less about the community and the guidelines or don't format questions. This makes it hard for people like you or me to answer questions. I do think that the moderation community could be more lenient.

Comment: Part of the reason for the moderation community acting the way it is are the guidelines, if they were re-written to accommodate for moderation and new users then you'd probably see a more friendly attitude. But that probably won't happen. If your getting free advice the least you could do is spell and check for on-topic-ness